# 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute '_meta' when trying to update user

Tags: django, django-views

In my app I am getting an error when trying to update a user info.

my code is the following:

```
def CandidateSignIn(request, uidb64, token):
    try:
        uid = force_text(urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64))
        user = MyUser.objects.get(pk=uid)
    except(TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, User.DoesNotExist):
        user = None

    if user is not None and account_activation_token.check_token(user, token):
        user.is_active = True
        user.save()
        login(request, user)

    registered  = False
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = TeamMembersFormUpdate(data=request.POST, instance=request.user)

        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.save()
            #registered = True
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('registration:HRlogin'))

        else:
            print("Error!")
    else:
        form = TeamMembersFormUpdate()
    return render(request,'candidateSignIn.html',
                            {'form':form,
                            'registered':registered})
```

and apparently I am getting the error from the line

```
form = TeamMembersFormUpdate(data=request.POST, instance=request.user)
```

do you have any idea on how to solve this ?

Comment: Why are you passing an instance here anyway? If the user has not yet registered, obviously they won't be logged in, so `request.user` will always be the anonymous user.

Comment: Because in my app. I create the user when the admin invite create a team et invite members. So the user is created only with the mail, and I send him a mail to finish registration with password first name last name. So yes the user is regsitred

Comment: @DanielRoseman little precision, it is working on local, I get the error on heroku on production

Comment: the user is registrered but has neved logged in

Comment: try passing the user instance that you got in 4 instead of request.user

Comment: Could you be a little more precise  ?

Comment: @Ben2pop I just answered please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are logging the user in at line

11: `login(request, user)`

but the middleware will not be updated unless you return from the view you are in so you are getting the same anonymous user instance

so you just replace the `request.user` with 'user' that you got in the line 4

It will do thing right

```
...
if request.method == "POST" and user:
    form = TeamMembersFormUpdate(data=request.POST, instance=user)
    #rest here
#if you have no such user 
else: 
    form = TeamMembersFormUpdate()
return render(request,'candidateSignIn.html',
                        {'form':form,
                        'registered':registered})
```